# It ain't nuthin' till I call it

Tags: meaning

*It ain't nuthin' till I call it.*

The source: Tsatsouline, P.: *The Naked Warrior*.
<sup>[http://www.amazon.com/dp/0938045555/?tag=stackoverfl08-20#reader_0938045555](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0938045555)</sup>

How do you understand the above proclamation? Given the fact that the quotation comes from a book concerning fitness and bodybuilding I intuitively suspect that the author wants to say that he overcomes any kind of the challange but what is the exact meaning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OP's link just takes me to a page on Amazon trying to sell me the book, where I can't see the cited text *in context*. But it's regurgitating [this earlier usage](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22snapped%20It%20ain%27t%20nuthin%27%20till%20I%20call%20it%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) (first recorded in *World Vision*, Volume 23, 1979)...

> *In fact, we are saying that "evangelical" doesn't mean anything until we say what it means — like the umpire who in an argument over a play at first base snapped, "**It ain't nuthin'** till I call it"*.

...which is itself a rehash of an earlier phrasing in [Proceedings of the American Gas Association (1949)](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22omnipotent%20power%20speaks%20reminds%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl)...

> *This ... reminds me of the remark attributed to Auggie Moran, the great National League umpire. As he put it: "They may be balls — They may be strikes. But **until I call them — they ain't nothin'**"*.

The idea being it's the ***umpire*** who [*calls the shots*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/call-the-shots) (it's *nuthin' = nothing = not important* what the players or spectators think - the referee's opinion is the only one that counts). This sense of ***call*** (2j: [***to rule on the status of*** (as a pitched ball or a player's action)](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/call)) is labeled "informal" by [Cambridge dictionaries](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/call) in their corresponding entry for the *noun* sense *(call = decision)*.

Essentially, the speaker is (*very* informally) saying that *he and only he* has the authority to pronounce on the matter in hand. It's not really an "idiom" - just an old sports-related metaphor occasionally recycled.

---

A similar usage - originally derived from opera, but now widespread in sporting contexts - is [*It ain't over till the fat lady sings*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It_ain%27t_over_till_the_fat_lady_sings) (don't assume the current state of an event is irreversible and clearly determines how or when the event will end - *things might still change, right up until the last moment*).

Comment: It might be worth noting that the phrase is associated with [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/169146/21080) anecdote...

Comment: @Micah: Indeed. Your comment prompted me to dig deeper into "first use" citations. It seems your "three umpires" anecdote originated in the early 70s, but I've edited my text to include a 1949 reference attributing the basic usage to a baseball player who was much in the public eye in the late 1800s. If that attribution is true (unlikely, I know) it goes back a *very* long way.

Comment: In addition, the quote has been interpreted (or extended ) to mean that we define or create reality subjectively (see paragraph 3 at http://www.biographybase.com/biography/Fish_Stanley.html). It's logical that such ideas can be related to advice or inspiration to motivate, encourage, etc., as the OP said he senses. For example, we can reframe an obstacle as a challenge, a weakness as a developmental opportunity, etc.

Comment: @Jim: Yeah - like I said, I can't see the exact "text in context" of OP's citation, so I can't say how far the usage has been "figuratively extended". But it should be easy enough to extrapolate the intended meaning in any given (valid) context, once you know the basic background. It's similar to what they say about [Schrödinger's cat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger%27s_cat) - *it ain't **anything** (it's neither alive nor dead) until we **look** at it*.

Comment: (*My* cat thinks Schrödinger's is old hat. She's working on a groundbreaking "time dilation" theory, which so far has enabled her to increase the amount of time spent sleeping from her natural 23 hours per day to 24.9 hours. And she fully expects to push it beyond 24 hours/day this year! :)